# RegEx via Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I do not know how to solve this coding puzzle with Javascript. I've never been working with Regular Expressions but I feel they are the best approach to solve it.

Let's say, I have this code:

```
let str = "abcdefabc";
let pattern = "abc";
```

What I need is to write the algorithm, that returns the array of arrays (two-dimensional) of indexes like this:

```
[ 
[1, 2, 3], 
[4, 5, 6], 
[7, 8, 9] 
]
```

where indexes are the positions of `pattern` letters in `str`. For example, with `str = 'abcdefabc'` and pattern `pattern = 'abc'` algo must return such arrays:

1. `[0, 1, 2]` (first `'abc'` inside str that matches `pattern`: "**abc**defabc");
2. `[6, 7, 8]` (last `'abc'` inside str that matches `pattern`: "abcdef**abc**"); these are obvious examples, but it must return those as well:
3. `[0, 1, 8]` because "**ab**cdefab**c**"
4. `[0, 7, 8]` because "**a**bcdefa**bc**"

I hope you got the logic. The order of `pattern` is important: `str = 'fox1423423man_united_x'` with `pattern ='fox'` must return `[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 21]]`;

`str = 'google` with `pattern ='fox'` must return `null` because there is no 'fox' somewhere in between;

`str = 'xof'` with `pattern ='fox'` must return `null` because the way the letters go is important;

All strings will be **lower-case**

Comment: A regular expression won't find overlapping matches. So it won't match `012` and also `018` and `078`

Comment: it's fine to solve without any of those

Comment: Then I would say: go ahead and do it without regex. Let us know when you have a specific problem while trying.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback! I was trying to solve it with iteration and it worked OK with simple examples. But if the pattern has over 1000 characters it worked badly. It's crazy to think that RegEx cannot help hm...

Comment: Please add the code you used to the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that solves it via recursion.
It uses the [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method to find the positions of the characters.

```js
function findTokenPositions(str, tokens) {
  let arr = [];
  function recurse (strpos=0, tok=0, accum=[]) {
    if (tok >= tokens.length) { arr.push(accum); return; }
    strpos = str.indexOf(tokens[tok], strpos);
    if (strpos < 0) { return; }
    accum[tok] = strpos;
    recurse(strpos+1, tok+1, [...accum])
    recurse(strpos+1, tok,   [...accum]);
  }
  recurse();
  return arr;
}

let tests = [ 
  ["abcdefabc", "abc"], 
  ["fox1423423man_united_x", "fox"], 
  ["hound", "fox"], 
  ["xof", "fox"]
];

tests.forEach(x => {
  console.log(x[0]+' : '+x[1]+' --> ' + JSON.stringify(findTokenPositions(x[0], x[1])))
});
```

And here's another function that uses regex to get the positions.
This only scans the string once.

```js
function getTokenPositions(str, tokens) {
  let positions = []; let base = []; let m;
  let re = new RegExp('['+tokens+']','gi');
  while (m = re.exec(str)) { 
    positions.push([m[0], m.index])
    if(m[0] === tokens[0]) { base.push([m.index]); }
  }
  for (let tok=1; tok < tokens.length; tok++) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i=0; i < positions.length; i++) {
      if (positions[i][0] === tokens[tok]) {
        let tmp = [...base];
        for (let j=0; j < tmp.length; j++) {      
          tmp[j][tok] = positions[i][1];
        }
        tmp.forEach(a=>arr.push([...a]));
      }
    }
    base = [...arr];
  }
  // only return the sorted
  return base.filter(x => x.every((v,i)=>(i===0||v>=x[i-1])));
}

let tests = [ 
  ["abcdefabc", "abc"], 
  ["fox1423423man_united_x", "fox"], 
  ["hound", "fox"], 
  ["xof", "fox"]
];

tests.forEach(x => {
  console.log(x[0]+' : '+x[1]+' --> ' + JSON.stringify(getTokenPositions(x[0], x[1])))
});
```

Comment: This algo is a pure gold for my task!! Exactly what needed.Thank you so much!

Comment: The fact that `indexOf` allows to search after a position really helps with this one. And it's super fast.  With regex you can also get index & lastIndex, but it not very handy to search after a specific position.

Comment: The more I code the more I realize how valuable recursion is. Never really tried it out. Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Recursion is cool, but it's often harder to understand what's really happening with it. Using normal iteration could be more efficient. More [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/179868/223732)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonably clean implementation, based on a simple function that finds all indices of a character in a string (or actually, more generally, all indices of a value in an iterable).

```js
const allIndices = (xs, t, s = 0) => 
  [...xs] .slice (s) .flatMap ((x, i) => x == t ? [i] : [])

const allMatches = (word, sub, i = 0) => 
  sub .length == 0
    ? [[]]
    : allIndices (word, sub [0], i) 
        .flatMap (j => allMatches (word, sub .slice (1), i + j + 1) .map (s => [i + j, ...s]))

console .log (allMatches ("abcdefabc", "abc"))
console .log (allMatches ("fox1423423man_united_x", "fox"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**`allIndices`** uses `flatMap` as a sort of filter that returns indices rather than values.

**`allMatches`** calls `allIndices` with the first character of the search string, and then recurs on the remainder of the word and the other character of the search string, combining the current index with those results.  It bottoms out when the search string is empty and returns a result containing just an empty array.

We could write a version with less index fiddling, but it would then need to slice and dice the main string much more often.

Comment: Very creative way of using ES6 style with recursion. Slicing upwards. I like this.